# Customize ResponseStatus Error code attribute

Tags: servicestack

I've been working with ServiceStack for a while and need to know if it's possible to customize a ResponseStatus object when an exception is thrown.

So I currently get a response like this:

```
{"responseStatus":{"errorCode":"PasswordNotValidException",
"message":"User Defined Error","errors":[]}}
```

I would like to update the "errorCode" field so it returns a custom error code that would probably come from an enum, like this:

```
{"responseStatus":{"errorCode":"PasswordNotValid",
"message":"User Defined Error","errors":[]}}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [ServiceStack's Error Handling wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling), it currently lists the potential error customizations available in ServiceStack.